# 'int' object is not subscriptable (function calling error)

Tags: python, encryption, error-handling, int

I'm attempting to break a vigenere cipher without knowing the key and I'm struggling to figure out my error since the caesar_break function seems to work perfectly fine on its own.

This is the code for the function i'm attempting to call:

```
def caesar_break( cipher, frequencies ): # help!
    alpha = ["A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" ,
             "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" , "U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z" ]
    dist_ls = []

    for key in alpha:
        poss_plaintxt = caesar_dec( cipher, key )
        counts = letter_counts( poss_plaintxt )
        observed = normalize( counts )
        dist = distance( observed, frequencies )
        dist_ls.append( (dist , poss_plaintxt , key) )
        can = dist_ls[ 0 ][ 0 ]
        can_t = 0
        for t in dist_ls:
            if t[ 0 ] < can:
                can = t[ 0 ]
                can_t = t

    return [ can_t[ 2 ], can_t[ 1 ] ]
```

This is what I have so far for my current function, I am not completely done with it, but I just need to figure out this error in order to move forward:

```
def vig_break( c, maxlen, frequencies ):
    from i in range( 1, maxlen ):
        break_ls = list(vig_break_for_length( c, i, frequencies ))

    print( break_ls ) #this print is unneeded, i just like to test my code as i go
```

For specificity this is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ciphers.py", line 310, in vig_break
    break_ls = list(vig_break_for_length( c, i, frequencies ))
  File "ciphers.py", line 288, in vig_break_for_length
    split_break = caesar_break( ciphertext, frequencies )
  File "ciphers.py", line 192, in caesar_break
    return [ can_t[ 2 ], can_t[ 1 ] ]
    TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `can_t` is initialized to 0. If `dist_ls` is empty, that loop is never entered, allowing no chance to set `can_t` to a subscriptable object. Alternatively, if `t[0] < can` is never true, that will also provide no opportunity to set `can_t` to something subscriptable.

Comment: Off-topic: Strongly suggest you start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you want other people to be able to easily read your code. It'll make it easier for you, too.

Comment: You should avoid changing the type of a variable half way through your code to avoid situations like this.